# jquery ajax change div content

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink, onclick

I have a page with a div in it with an an id centeredmenu. When the page first loads it has a menu inside the div with 10 options. each one of these options has a different named id such as menu2, menu3 and so on with a blank href link. On inital load i can change to any menu, once this has completed i cannot select any other menu and change the content of the div again with the new menu

my script for this is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#menu2").click(function(){
        $('#centeredmenu').load('menu2.php');
       }); 
       $("#menu3").click(function(){
        $('#centeredmenu').load('menu3.php');
       });
       $("#menu4").click(function(){
        $('#centeredmenu').load('menu4.php');
       });
       $("#menu5").click(function(){
        $('#centeredmenu').load('menu5.php');
       });
       $("#menu6").click(function(){
        $('#centeredmenu').load('menu6.php');
       });
       $("#menu7").click(function(){
        $('#centeredmenu').load('menu7.php');
       });
       $("#menu8").click(function(){
        $('#centeredmenu').load('menu8.php');
       });
       $("#menu9").click(function(){
        $('#centeredmenu').load('menu9.php');
       });
       $("#menu10").click(function(){
        $('#centeredmenu').load('menu10.php');
       });
       $("#menu11").click(function(){
        $('#centeredmenu').load('menu11.php');
       });
     });
</script>
```

So i first load the page and select say menu3 which then loads menu3 fine, all sunsequent menus will then not load unless i refresh the page and go back to the start again and select the other menu i want.
Your help is greatly appreciated
P

Comment: can you set up a fiddle with this? are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @haz0rd Lost me on that one lol

Comment: @haz0rd it is almost as if the jquery is not working. Normally you would not see a pge refresh which i do not get on initial change of menu. when i select subsequent menus you do see the page trying to reload which should not happen

Comment: [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a way for us to see exactly what you're working with and be able to reproduce your problem. if the page is loading sounds like you might have some <a> tags you are setting this too? you should make sure to nullify their hrefs with # like adeneo mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably overwriting the menu when you load the new content, so you'll need a delegated event handler:

```
$('#centeredmenu').on('click', '[id^="menu"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#centeredmenu').load(this.id + '.php');
});
```

also, elements with empty href's does reload the page, you should be using the `#` sign in your href's and prevent the default action in the event handler.

Comment: Many thanks guys, I was using # on the hrefs, the event handler solved the issue using the above snippet :)